# jQPlot - remove circles for no data in line chart

Tags: json, jqplot

I am currently working with a line chart where x axis = Period length (last 12 months from current date), y axis = Purchase value. However, I have data (Purchase figures) only from 2012 December but my chart starts showing the line from 2012 August. This means, there is no data prior to Jan 2013 and line must start from month Jan.

Problem: the chart shows Marker options (circle) even for the months where there is no data. the circles are shown on the grid 0.

Question: how can I remove the circles where there is no data?

Tried: hideZeros : true, but this seems work for 'pointLabels' only.

```
 ,markerOptions: {
                show: true,    
                style: 'filledCircle', 
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Prior to plot your data, you can delete those who have NULL value.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This worked. My problem was, I was removing 0 than Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to plot your data, you can delete those who have NULL (or 0) value, you will not see them on your plot then.